# Legislative Capacity Exception to Definition of 'Public Authority' in Aarhus Convention

Tags: legislature, environmental

I've encountered some difficulty in interpreting the Aarhus Convention Implementation Guide (https://unece.org/DAM/env/pp/Publications/Aarhus_Implementation_Guide_interactive_eng.pdf) in its explanation of the convention's provision that '*bodies or institutions acting in a judicial or legislative capacity*' are not considered to be a '*public authority*'.

For one, page 49 includes the below explanation:

*'As the activities of public authorities in drafting regulations, laws and normative acts is expressly covered by that
article (article 8), it is logical to conclude that the Convention does not consider these activities to be acting in a “legislative capacity”.*

My understanding of this is that a public body drafting legislation is not acting in a 'legislative capacity' and therefore may be considered a public body (the cases in which the 'legislative capacity' exception would apply are unclear to me in light of this).

However, a later paragraph on the same page suggests the following:

*It should also be remembered that, while bodies or institutions acting in a legislative or judicial capacity do not fall under
the definition of “public authorities,” a number of the Convention’s obligations, in particular those found in articles 3 and 9,
are placed not on public authorities but rather upon the Party itself.*

It appears that one instance of an institution not qualifying as a 'public authority' yet subject to the convention as a 'party' is the below example:

*Legislative bodies may need to
enact legislation to adjust a particular Party’s legislative framework to comply with the Convention.*

It remains, therefore, unclear to me whether or not legislatures drafting legislation qualify as 'public authorities' under the Aarhus Convention. Is it that they are bound both as parties and public authorities?

I apologise for any ignorance on my part if I have completely misinterpreted the interpretation guide.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: For background: "The UNECE Convention on Access to Information, Public Participation in Decision-making and Access to Justice in Environmental Matters was adopted on 25th June 1998 in the Danish city of Aarhus at the Fourth Ministerial Conference in the 'Environment for Europe' process. 
Together with its Protocol on Pollutant Release and Transfer Registers, it protects every person’s right to live in an environment adequate to his or her health and well-being." https://unece.org/environment-policy/public-participation/aarhus-convention/introduction

Answer (score 2):

### It’s not what you’re called, it’s what you do

The convention applies to executive functions no matter what branch of government conducts them. It excludes legislative and judicial functions no matter what breach of government does those.

Anyone who carries out executive functions is a ‘*public authority*’ while they are carrying out those functions, but they aren’t while they are carrying out a different function. For example, in a Westminster system the Minister for X is a public authority while carrying out their ministerial duties but not while carrying out their parliamentary duties.

There is an exemption built in collaboration between the executive and the legislature in law-making is implicitly not legislative action by the executive.

A party, is a party to the treaty; like Belgium.